# Blender bones are coming out of mesh and deforming it, weight paints are fine

Tags: animation, rigify

I am using rigify, and I am making all of the weights myself because automatic is TERRIBLE at reading my mesh. I have repainted it 1000 times and scoured the internet and found nothing. The fingers are now deforming whenever i move, and the bones are leaving the mesh whenever i move them. The tutorial i am following (TomCAT) shows him pressing automatic and it moves perfectly.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SvOunbZ_EAsWLOzpRwriw98oCuMoOv04/view?usp=share_link
[image: Mesh deformed]

[[image: Bone leaving mesh][2]]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SvOunbZ_EAsWLOzpRwriw98oCuMoOv04/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the *N panel > Item > Vertex Weights*, if I select a vertex of the finger, for some reason it is assigned to several vertex groups that it should not be part of. Giving its position it should be only part of *DEF-f_middle.03.R*:

[image]

So first of all you need to remove the vertices of the hand from all groups:

[image]

Then you need to paint each phallange:

[image]